# How do I fix WHS 2011 failing to install KB4535102; return code 80092004?

Tags: windows-home-server

I am seeing this error...
[image: install error]

for this update...
[image: update details]

How do I get the update to install correctly?

Comment: See if anything here helps>>>>https://www.askwoody.com/forums/topic/whs2011-kb4535102-fails-returns-80092004/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Moab got me pushed in the right direction. Thanks!

---

Turns out Windows Updates are now `SHA-2` signed. If your server doesn't have the proper updates to process `SHA-2` signatures then updates will fail.

So, to fix things, two updates need to be installed:

- KB4474419 ⏬ [download](http://www.catalog.update.microsoft.com/Search.aspx?q=KB4474419%202008%20R2%20x64%202019-09)
  <sup>SHA-2 code signing support update for Windows Server 2008 R2, Windows 7, and Windows Server 2008</sup>
- KB4490628 ⏬ [download](http://www.catalog.update.microsoft.com/Search.aspx?q=KB4490628%202008%20R2%20x64)
  <sup>Servicing stack update for Windows 7 SP1 and Windows Server 2008 R2 SP1</sup>

Once installed SHA-2 signed updates will work.

Last step...

- Rerun Windows Update and `KB4535102` will install successfully.

Answer (score -1):

Laptop HP nc6320 ,1GB RAM

Clear Win7pro 32 bit installed from DVD without SP,
then SP1 was add and above 100 updates from the internet.
The upgrade stopped at unsuccessful attempt of of:
KB4535102 and KB4516065 installation
(At this phase only these two updates were  found)
The issue was resolved by manual update of KB4490628 only.
(after that KB4516065 was installed at first, then computer reset
and KB4535102 was installed successfully.
Search for updates found few other updates to install).